# JAVA runtime erroe: JNI error has occured

Tags: java, cmd, java-native-interface, runtime

I have downloaded whole java 3 times and still get this error after executing in cmd
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyLeg.png)

Comment: The error message clearly says that you have compiled your code with a more recent version than your jre.

Comment: Perhaps you did not compile what you thought.  Run `javac hello.java` (if you named it lower case) rather than `javac hello.class`.  Then `java hello`.

Comment: Your `javac` command is failing because you are giving it a class file - the command should be `javac hello.java`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to compile code with exactly the same version of Java you are trying to use.

To do so, make sure that both:

```
java -version
javac -version
```

produce the same version information.

Let's say you have file: `Hello.java`

```
public class Hello {
  public static void main(String [] arg) {
    System.out.println("Hello world!\n");
  }
}
```

Make sure to compile it:

```
java Hello.java
```

and then, run it

```
javac Hello
```

Your `%PATH%` variable should point to very same JDK and JRE if you want to compile and run the code.

Answer (score 0):

in cmd, type where java, remove all other java path from environment variable other than the one from jdk directory